# How to find the slowest datanodes?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I install one HDFS cluster that have 15 datanodes. Sometimes the writing performance of the entire hdfs cluster is slow.

How i to find the slowest datanode,which node can cause this problem。

Comment: https://hortonworks.com/blog/part-6-of-data-lake-3-0-a-self-diagnosing-data-lake/

This may be of some help

Comment: @Abhinav,my hdfs version is `2.6.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of a slow datanode is a bad disk.  Disk timeout errors (EIO) defaults range from 30 to 90 seconds so any activity on that disk will take a long time.

You can check this by looking at `dfs.datanode.data.dir` in your hdfs-site.xmls for every datanode and verifying that each of the directories mentioned actually work. 
For example:

- run `ls` on the directory
- `cd` into the directory
- create a file under the directory
- write into a file under the directory
- read contents of a file under the directory

If any of these activities don't work or take a long time, then that's your problem.

You can also run `dmesg` on each host and look for disk errors.

**Additional Information**

- [HDFS DataNode Scanners and Disk Checker Explained](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/12/hdfs-datanode-scanners-and-disk-checker-explained/)
- [HDFS-7430](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-7430) - Rewrite the BlockScanner to use O(1) memory and use multiple threads
- https://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive